# SQL query help with GROUPing and nested queries

Tags: sql, group-by, nested, grouping, query-help

Given are two tables,

- Table `A` containing `customerid`, `lastchange`, `internallink`
- Table `B` containing `internallink`, `turnover`

*(I'm simplyfying here and changing it to a generic example, the actual structure is more complex. SQL dialect for now is mySQL.)*

The only unique thing (per table) is the internallink.
There are several records in A with the same customerID, different dates in lastchange, and different internallink values.
There are other items linked with this; I cannot change the tables.

**I need the recordIDs from A which are the most recent for a customer (highest lastchange value of all with the same customerID) *and* to which the entries in B which match a certain value condition are linked.**

I think the

```
SELECT `internallink` FROM `B` WHERE (`turnover` > 10000)
```

part is not the issue.

I got this far:

```
SELECT `customerID`, MAX(`lastchange`)
  FROM `A` 
 WHERE `lastchange` IN (SELECT `internallink` FROM `B` 
                         WHERE `turnover` > 10000)
 GROUP BY `customerID`;
```

Alas, that statement gives wrong results, because above will return me customerIDs for which the most recent value does not fulfill the criteria, but some older did - it selects the oldest that did, and returns this. But in case the most recent entry is below threshold, the customerID should not turn up at all.

Where did I go wrong, and what is the correct approach to this?

Sample Data
Table A

```
customerid   lastchange   internallink
         3   2010-02-11   11
         3   2010-09-04   12
         3   2010-10-22   13
         3   2010-11-23   14
         4   2010-05-05   15
         4   2010-12-01   16
         5   2010-11-28   17
         5   2010-11-29   18
```

Table B

```
internallink  turnover
          11     47000
          12     11000
          13      8000
          14     15000
          15     17000
          16     23000
          17     50000
          18     10000
```

The actual threshold in my tests is 12000.
You can see customerID should not be in the result set, since the most recent entry is below the threshold.

The result set should be (3,2010-11-23)(4,2010-12-01) - but currently it also contains (5,2010-11-28), which is wrong.

---

Getting a bit closer (with your help, thanks!), these two statements both work:

SELECT customerID, MAX(lastchange), internallink FROM A GROUP BY customerID;
   SELECT internallink FROM B WHERE (turnover > 12000);

Now all I need is the intersection of both... with the correct logic!

Comment: Is there a way you can post some sample data?  Just a few records per table?  It's difficult to visualize the problem with what you've written.

Comment: You might be interested in this [stack-exchange proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review?referrer=aWNm_PdciyFqjFW8CUacGw2 "code review"). It's almost ready to begin beta, just needs a few more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of testing and some research, I found this solution, and I post
this in case anybody else should face a similar problem.

An additional table "cache" keeps copies of the most recent entries in table A, reducing the complexity a lot. It is kept current by using triggers like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER sync_a_insert AFTER INSERT ON a FOR EACH ROW 
    INSERT INTO cache (`customerID`, `internallink`) VALUES (NEW.`customerID`,NEW.`internallink`);
CREATE TRIGGER sync_a_update AFTER UPDATE ON a FOR EACH ROW 
    UPDATE cache SET `internallink` = NEW.`internallink` WHERE (`customerID` = NEW.`customerID`);
CREATE TRIGGER sync_a_delete BEFORE DELETE ON a FOR EACH ROW 
    DELETE FROM cache WHERE `customerID` = OLD.`customerID`;
```

For INSERT and UPDATE, those triggers go off after the fact, so the entries in Table a are complete before the cache updates. For DELETE, the cache needs to be updated before the original entry vanishes.

Once this is in place, everything else becomes simple:

```
SELECT `customerID` FROM cache WHERE `internallink` IN 
    (SELECT `internallink` FROM b WHERE (`turnover` > 10000));
```

For me, this is a viable solution, and it even speeds up the lookups. Of course there is a cost in DB size, but I think the performance is much better overall - as long as there is at least one more read access than write access, there is an improvement.

The answers you gave were, however, very helpful to me. I learned a bunch of things from them and from trying to follow your advice (even putting some of it to use in other places already). Thanks to all who replied to my question!

Answer (score 1):

The following query should do what you want. It is **not** the most performant way to write this kind of query. But it's using standard SQL and it executes in any database.

The works like this: The inner subquery finds all customerids along with the latest changedate. For each such pair (customerid, lastchange), we find the original row in table A. Having found a row in table A, we use the internallink to find a matching record in B, but only if the associated turnover is greater than 10000.

```
drop table a;
drop table b;

create table a(
   customerid   int  not null
  ,lastchange   date not null
  ,internallink int  not null
);

create table b(
   internallink int not null
  ,turnover     int not null
);

insert into a values(3, date '2010-02-11', 11);
insert into a values(3, date '2010-09-04', 12);
insert into a values(3, date '2010-10-22', 13);
insert into a values(3, date '2010-11-23', 14);
insert into a values(4, date '2010-05-05', 15);
insert into a values(4, date '2010-12-01', 16);
insert into a values(5, date '2010-11-28', 17);
insert into a values(5, date '2010-11-29', 18);

insert into b values(11, 47000);
insert into b values(12, 11000);
insert into b values(13,  8000);
insert into b values(14, 15000);
insert into b values(15, 17000);
insert into b values(16, 23000);
insert into b values(17, 50000);
insert into b values(18, 10000);

select a.customerid
      ,a.lastchange
      ,a.internallink
      ,b.turnover
  from a
  join b on (a.internallink = b.internallink)
 where b.turnover > 10000
   and (a.customerid, a.lastchange) in(select customerid,max(lastchange)
                                         from a
                                     group by customerid);
```

Comment: Looks good, although it seems to cut off too much - but my current question is: there is a more efficent way, then? Just not standard-SQL? The Problem I had was to use "IN", i want just one column but have two and no way of selectiong just one for matching.

Answer (score 0):

This works in sql server - I'm not sure if mySql has a similar ranking functions.

```
select a.id, a.lastchange, b.turnover, a.rownumber from B b inner join 
(SELECT id, lastchange, internallink, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY lastchange DESC) AS 'rownumber'
FROM A) a on b.internallink = a.internallink
where a.rownumber = 1 and b.turnover > 5000
```

The "ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY lastchange DESC) AS 'rownumber'" means...

I want to group all the same ids together and order them by lastchange by desc after that count each row. Oh and name that column rownumber.

```
id  lastchange    internallink  rownumber
1   2010-01-03    2           1
1   2010-01-02    1           2
1   2010-01-01    1           3
2   2010-01-04    2           1
```

Selecting any record with a rownumber of 1 will return the last modified record of an id.

Comment: @foo - MySQL doesn't have analytic functions, but this article explains how you can fake them: http://explainextended.com/2009/03/08/analytic-functions-sum-avg-row_number/

Comment: It will take me some time to get this translated / emulated in whole, so I can test it. And more time to understand it first. I wish there was a simpler way to do this...

Comment: @foo - The link that APC provide is helpful. When you are digesting it, try different variations of the query (changing what's getting partitioned and/or what's getting ordered) and view the results - it should help you make sense of things quicker.  Good luck.

Comment: I have to agree, that link is very useful, and I can recommend it!